# floating and integer power difference in Python

Tags: python

```
>>> int(78^30.0)
579212706592939038891905505293692501207079252042132226048
>>> int(78^30)
579212706592939054456238001058547123517325472344282497024
```

Why are they different? I know that 30.0 is a floating point and 30 is an integer but the calculation must be the same. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Floating point numbers are **not** precise in the same way integers are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem caused by the internal representation of floating point numbers, which uses a fixed number of binary digits to represent a decimal number. Some decimal numbers can't be represented exactly in binary, resulting in small roundoff errors.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1. effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm</sup></sup>